# Windows Crash after FilterReturnNetBuffferList routine?

Tags: windows, drivers, ndis, windows-kernel, filter-driver

I am writing Light Weight Filter Driver in which i wrote FilterRecieve function which replaces the NBL recieved by its own allocated NBL and called NdisFIndicateRecieveNetBufferLists with this new NBL. But as FilterReturnNetBuffferList function is getting called windows is getting crashed. After crash analysis it is showing the windows got crashed in E1G6032E module at E1000ReturnNetBufferLists+9.

Is it because I changed the NBL in receive routine? Do I have to undo all the changes done in Receive while in FilterReturnNetBuffferList?

Comment: this issue has been resolved. i hope windows development community could get more stronger as is linux. about  answer if you are changing NBL in receive you have to take them in a local linked list and at regain of ownership return the original NBL through FilterReturnNetBuffferList.